# How to use join in solr in order to get result from both the cores?

Tags: join, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have two cores:

core 1: BookID, Venue, Title, Authors, PubDate

core 2: BookID, Text, Referenecs, Size, LastUpdated

> http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?fl=Title,%20Venue,%20Authors,%20PubDate&q={!join%20from=PaperID%20to=fileName%20fromIndex=core2%20}size:15870

The above query returns zero results as:

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">0</int>
      <lst name="params">
         <str name="q">{!join from=PaperID to=fileName fromIndex=PapersIndex }size:15870</str>
         <str name="fl">Title, Venue</str>
      </lst>
   </lst>
   <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" />
</response>
```

I don't know how the solr join works. Why does it give zero results?

Answer (score 6):

Joins in Solr can't return results from both sides. Think of a join as "filtering the results by matching from a different core" (i.e. an INNER JOIN in regular SQL).

The reason why your example gives zero results is probably because you're joining the *ID* of one core against the *SIZE* in the other core. You want to join ID against ID (i.e. the common ID in both cores).

But you'll still only be able to return data from a single core / collection.

The solution to this is usually to index everything into the same core, although there's support for joins with data from both sides using streaming expressions (where each result is returned and then joined from both cursors), but I don't recommend basing your queries and index design on that from the scratch.

Comment: @ MatsLindh Thanks for guidance... actually in the above query i am comparing ID against ID. the size is a condition and field of the second core. I need result from the first core based on the condition of the second core  thats is return some attribute of the first core, where size is 15870. where size is the field of second core.

Answer (score 0):

Solved out... pretty simple tried out the following query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=*:*&%20fl=%20Title,Year&fq={!join%20from=BookID%20fromIndex=core2%20to=BookID}Year:2000
```

You can get fields from the first core as per some criteria based on second core.

Like I need `field1, field2,..fieldn` from core1 where `core2.field="something"`